# android try socket to route error

Tags: android

when i try to socket to a wifi route,here is my code,but i shows error

```
Button.OnClickListener buttonConnectOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        wifiInfo = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (wifiInfo.isConnected()) {

        if(!connected){

             try {
                // socket = new Socket("192.168.1.1", 2001);
            // Log.v("test4","test4");
             /*Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this,
             "Connected Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             msg.show();*/
             //Log.v("test5","test5");
             socket = new Socket("192.168.1.1",2001);
                  dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                  changeConnectionStatus(true);} 
             catch (UnknownHostException e) {changeConnectionStatus(false);} 
             catch (IOException e) {changeConnectionStatus(false);}}
        else{
            try {socket.close();
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this,
            "Disconnected Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
                  changeConnectionStatus(false);} 
            catch (UnknownHostException e) {changeConnectionStatus(false);}
            catch (IOException e) {changeConnectionStatus(false);}}}
        else {Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                "Wifi is not connected !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                msg.show();}
}};
```

the error in logcat is

> > 06-26 18:37:48.190: W/dalvikvm(11911): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a571f8)
> >     06-26 18:37:48.205: E/AndroidRuntime(11911): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> >     06-26 18:37:48.205: E/AndroidRuntime(11911): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> >     06-26 18:37:48.205: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
> >     06-26 18:37:48.205: E/AndroidRuntime(11911):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` means you will need to use Thread or AsyncTask for doing heavy task in separate Thread instead if main Thread

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to open a socket on the main application thread. Network I/O needs to be conducted on a background thread, so it does not tie up the user interface.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTask is the easiest way to start as many have mentioned. You can find a quick tutorial here:[AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use internet on main `Thread` which is not possible, so for this issue put your `try-catch` code inside a `AsyncTask`.

*EDIT:*

[Android Background Processing with Threads, Handlers and - Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) might help you.